# Can you use ADO to edit table schema in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to edit the text field length in every table in a database. Basically, the account numbers are currently a text field of length 7. We need to widden them to 9. I know I can go through every table where the ACCT_NUM is and change it (there are about 100), but I'm trying to write some code to handle it, by looping through all the tables. So far, I've gotten to this point:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, Array(Empty, Empty, "ACCOUNT"))

While Not rs.EOF
    If rs![Column_Name] = "ACCT_NUM" Then
        If rs![CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] = 7 Then
            'the following line generates the this error: Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be alimitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype.
            rs![CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] = 9 
        End If
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

I know when editing records using DAO, I would use something like "recordset.Edit", but there doesn't appear to be a ADO equivolent.

Anyone know how I can do this? I'm not married to the idea of using ADO, so if there's some other way of doing this, I'll happily recode!

---

EDIT

---

With @HansUp 's help, here is the solution. I'll clean this up a little, but here you go:

```
Public Sub sp_change()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim s As String, buf As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    i = 0

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If ((tbl.Attributes And dbSystemObject) = 0) And ((tbl.Attributes And dbAttachedODBC) = 0) And ((tbl.Attributes And dbAttachedTable) = 0) And ((tbl.Attributes And dbAttachExclusive) = 0) Then
            Debug.Print "Processing table: " & tbl.Name
            For Each fld In tbl.Fields
                If fld.Name = "ACCT_NUM" And fld.Size = 7 Then
                    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & tbl.Name & " ALTER COLUMN ACCT_NUM TEXT(9);"
                    i = i + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print "Edited " & i & " instances."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say DAO is off limits.  I would use it to look for ACCT_NUM among the fields in each TableDef, then use ADO for the DDL statement Larry suggested.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN ACCT_NUM TEXT(9)"

Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        If fld.name = "ACCT_NUM" And fld.Size = 7 Then
            CurrentProject.Connection.Execute Replace(strDdl, "table_name", tdf.name)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next fld
Next tdf
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

If your Access version is earlier than 2000, the Replace() function will not be available, so you'll need to use a different method to create the DDL statement.

Comment: I didn't know you could use ALTER statements within Access. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with ADO by sending DDL commands to the database:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN ACCT_NUM TEXT(9)
```

You can get the table names by looping over the schema.

Alternatively, to actually change the database definition in procedural code you have to use another library, ADOX.  I've never been able to find good documentation or a good tutorial on using this library from Delphi, which is where I do most of my ADO work.

Comment: I normally do most of my work with DAO. When I was searching online I came across schema reading with ADO, but couldn't figure out how to actually edit it.